# SQL Server : print looping SELECT result with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

With T-SQL, can I print to the user (with `PRINT` or `RAISERROR`...) a list of a table lines that would meet a criteria using some loop?

Ex

```
BEGIN LOOP
    PRINT 'The name John was found for id = '

    SELECT id 
    FROM MyTable 
    WHERE Name = 'John'
END LOOP when DONE
```

Comment: Why would you want to use a loop for this??

Comment: Why is there a requirement to print or raiserror?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: As M. Ali's answer indicates: try to avoid thinking about loops in SQL. Instead think in terms of sets, and what action you want to happen to the items of the set, whether all of them or only some of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe something like...

```
SELECT 'The name John was found for id = ' + CAST(id AS VARCHAR(20))
from MyTable 
where Name='John'
```